# Trying to get cellEntered connection to work with QTableWidget (I want to trigger one or more callbacks)

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I am trying to get a callback when a cell is entered **either by clicking or navigating** into with arrow or tab keys (**basically when it gets focus**.)  I have tried many of the different connections to no avail (either they flat out are never called or when they are, self.currentItem() returns None.)  Once the cell has focus, I want to know what the row & col are so that I can pop up an appropriate dialog for the user to select and then fill out the appropropriate cell.

I've been unable to get this to work with my project, so I asked chatAI to generate an example.  Turns out that AI isn't as good as we think it is ;-)
Here is an example that should work but doesn't :-/ (handle_cell_focus_changed is never called) :

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem
import sys


class TableWidget(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.setRowCount(3)
        self.setColumnCount(3)

        for row in range(self.rowCount()):
            for column in range(self.columnCount()):
                item = QTableWidgetItem(f"({row}, {column})")
                self.setItem(row, column, item)

        self.cellEntered.connect(self.handle_cell_focus_changed)

    def handle_cell_focus_changed(self, row, column):
        print(f"Cell ({row}, {column}) has focus")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    table_widget = TableWidget()
    table_widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

self.itemEntered.connect(self.handleItemEntered) works great when moving the mouse around, but I need to know when the user navigates into the cell as well as when the user clicks on a cell.

```
self.cellClicked.connect(self.item_selection_changed)
```

works fine.

Comment: Yes, ChatGPT is not as good as *too many* people believe. But, most importantly, before trying to use an AI (which, as wonderful as it may be, it still has limited capabilities), you should just **study the documentation**. [`cellEntered`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#cellEntered) "is emitted when the mouse cursor **enters** a cell. [...] is only emitted when `mouseTracking` is turned on". Use [`cellClicked`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#cellClicked) or, better, [`currentCellChanged`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#currentCellChanged), which also considers keyboard navigation.

Comment: @musicamante I want to know when the cell is selected (before any changes have occured).  I want to know when the user clicks on a cell as well as when a user navigates to the cell.

Comment: @musicamante As you may have inferred above, I have an application I am developing and it has become too complicated to post here.  I have read the documentation (perhaps not as thoroughly as you) and have tried many different solutions in my own code.  It was only out of frustration that I went to openAI to give me a working example (which, it turns out, doesn't work.)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you are writing, specifically the "before any changes have occurred". The `cellClicked` and `currentCellChanged` *specifically* do what you are asking: call the connected function when a cell is clicked with the mouse or is selected using keyboard navigation. What is it that doesn't work for you with those signals?

Comment: @musicamante thank you for suggesting currentCellChanged.  This works for me.  I did not dig into that because I read it as the current cell (contents) changed.  Again, thank you for your help.

Comment: I understand the confusion: the "content change" you're referring to is actually provided by the [`cellChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#cellChanged) signal (and its related [`itemChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#itemChanged). While those names are quite similar, there is a fundamental difference: the "current" part. The `cellChanged` signals that *one cell* has changed [its contents] (no matter if it's "the current", aka, the selected one), while `currentCellChanged` tells that the *reference to the "current cell"* (aka, the selection) has changed.

Comment: Considering the *verbosity* of Qt, those signals could probably have better names: for instance `cellDataChanged` might be better. But, well, Qt is already *extremely* verbose (leading to very and sometimes annoying long lines of code). Let's just stick with the current naming (which makes sense, anyway), and be more careful with checking the documentation... checking it every time might be annoying sometimes, but that's better than having *even longer* names :-)